# How can I put these words in the same line with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to put [these words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW8vw.jpg) on the same line. I tried all of the `display` options, also tried with `text-align`. Nothing worked.

snippet

```html
<h3 id="trying">
        If you have time, you should read more about this incredible human being on his 
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Borlaug" target="_blank">
        Wikipedia Entry
      </a>.
    </h3>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and edit your question accordingly. This looks like you might either have a larger amount of sideways margin/padding on the headline element, or have it inside a container with limited with. Of course specifying different `display` values won’t change much about that.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;`, but you could have overflow

Comment: thanks zgood, I used that with margin-left and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

One simple method is to increase the width of h3 tag because the h3 tag is a block type element

```css
h3{
width:900px;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="trying">If you have time, you should read more about this incredible human being on his <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Borlaug" target="_blank">Wikipedia Entry</a>.</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to the `width` of the container that is the cause most probably.

```
#trying{
   width:100%
}
```

It will be the same as the parent container.